Cyclic Covers: Formula for Line Bundles
Let $C$ be an elliptic curve and $p: D \to C$ an etale cover of degree $2$, especially faithfully flat.
In this answer Mohan claims that there is a  $2$-torsion line bundle $L$ of $C$ (ie $L^{\otimes 2} \cong \mathcal{O}_C$) such that $p^*L=\mathcal{O}_{D}$.
Question: How to deduce it?
Some considerations: A degree $2$ cover is a cyclic cover, so by general theory (think standard source is Esnault's Lectures on Vanishing Theorems  the cover can be characterized as follows:
One can find a line bundle $M$ on $C$ such that $p_* \mathcal{O}_D \cong \mathcal{O}_C \oplus M^{-1}$. Note, $M$ (resp $M^{-1}$) appears to be a promising candidate for such $L$, but I not see how to such two things:
(A) that $M$ is $2$-torsion, ie $M^{\otimes 2} \cong \mathcal{O}_C$ and
(B) $p^*M=\mathcal{O}_{D}$
Could somebody sketch the idea how to see this?
Generalization attempt: Presumably this generalizes to $n$-cyclic branched covers $\pi: X' \to X$ with branched locus $B \subset X$ (ie, such that $X'-\pi^{-1}(B) \to X-B$ is etale $n$-cover): Then I would expect for a line bundle $L$ satisfying $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{X'}= \oplus_{d=0}^{n-1}(L^{-1})^{\otimes d}$
that (A) generalizes to $L^{\otimes n} \cong \mathcal{O}_{X}(B)$ and (B) to $\pi^*L=\mathcal{O}_{X'}(\pi^{-1}(B))$
#Edit: Let me add that *Exercise 2.7 in Chap IV from Hartshorne discusses partially this problem.

The cover is a $\mu_2$-torsor. Push it out along the inclusion $\mu_2\to\mathbf{G}_m$.

@AlexYoucis: So by this general machinery (pushouts along group hom $G \to H$ map $G$-torsors $H$-torsors; so the algebro-geometric version of $(H \times X)/G$ this inclusion induces a $\Bbb G_m$-torsor, so a line bundle on $C$ - let me guess using notation from above $D \mapsto M$ where latter satisfies $p_* \mathcal{O}_D \cong \mathcal{O}_C \oplus M^{-1}$.. In terms of Galois coho to pushout construction gives a group hom $H^1(X, \mu_2) \to H^1(X, \Bbb G_m)$ and as it respects structure we would get $M^2=O_C$. That's answers (A). What about (B)? Can it also be read up from this?

Yes, because by definition the $\mu_2$-torsor is trivialized on $D$ and so is the associated line bundle.

PS, this answer may be useful to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4644479/principal-bundle-or-torsor-for-a-diagonalizable-group-over-a-torus/4646951#4646951

@AlexYoucis: Right, I see. So we would have a functorially consistent diagram of $H^1$'s with horizontal maps $H^1(X,G) \to H^1(X,H)$ induced by this pushout construction and vertical maps $H^1(X,G) \to H^1(X',H)$ induced by pullbacks of $G$-torsors along $X' \to X$. And the claim of (B) follows from commutativity of the square, right?

(cont) What about the "Generalization attempt" part? So away from branching locus part  your argumentation from previous applies again. What about (A) & (B) for brached covers? Eg, my naive guess $L^n=O_X(B)$? Clearly, there could something happen something strange only inside branch locus $B$. But why for eg not say $L^n=O_X(2B)$? Is it possible to control this part?

@AlexYoucis: Maybe I should add as additional input that the branched locus has purely codim $1$, but I'm pretty sure that for cyclic covers this should hold automatically. I expect $B$ to be $V_+(s)$ for a global section of $L^n$, then "branched (A)" - ie $L^n=O_X(B)$ - should follow tautologically. What about "branched (B)"? Do you see to get $\pi^*L=\mathcal{O}_{X'}(\pi^{-1}(B))$?

I'm not sure you can see explicitly what happens (which is explained in Esnault's book) just from pure thought with the $\mu_n$-torsor approach. Perhaps you can, but any way I see to do it requires doing something similar to what Esnault does.

@AlexYoucis: One nitpick on the argument in etale/non-ramified case for problem (A): So we exploit that $H^1(X, \mu_2) \to H^1(X, \Bbb G_m)$ is a group homo, so respects the group structure on both sides. Then in order to get $M^2=O_C$ (where $M_a$ is the image of $2$-cover $a: D \to C$), we only need to see that $2a=0$ with resp Abelian group structure of $H^1(X, \mu_2)$, as the latter is by direct calc a $2$-torsion group so technically we are done.

(cont)  What I'm wondering about, what is actually the geometric object corresponding to the $2$-twist $2a$ of torsor $a$ wrt to the group structure of $H^1(X, \mu_2)$? Is this just the construction $D \times D/\mu_2$ (so taking product & moding out diagonal action)? In other words, group structure in $H^1(X, \mu_2)$ indicates that the $\mu$-torsors/equiv themselves form a group and the question is what is its multiplication operation?

The group operation is given by contracted product as you said (although diagonal needs to be interpreted correctly $g(d,d')=(gd,g^{-1}d')$.)

I am writing this answer only to clarify (and my name appears in the question) and the comments are adequate.
I will just deal with (A) and (B). The results are much more general and the proofs are similar. So, let $p:D\to C$ be an etale cover of smooth curves of degree 2. (Tacitly, one has assumed $D$ is connected, otherwise the result is false).
So, assume $D$ is connected, $C$ irreducible, then $D$ is irreducible, smooth and $g(D)-1=2(g(C)-1)$ by Riemann-Hurwitz. Let $p_*O_D=O_C\oplus L$. Since $h^0(O_D)=1$, we get that $h^0(L)=0$ and thus $L$ is non-trivial.
$$1-g(D)=\chi(O_D)=\chi(O_C)+\chi(L)=2(1-g(C))+\deg L$$
by Riemann-Roch. Thus $\deg L=0.$
Since $p_*O_D$ is an $O_C$-algebra, we have the natural multiplication map which is $O_C$ linear, $L^2\to O_C\oplus L$. This map can not be zero, otherwise, $O_D$ will have nilpotents. Composing with the projection, we have a map $L^2\to L$. If this map is non-zero, since both are degree zero, this must be an isomorphism and then $L\cong O_C$, a contradiction. So, the map $L^2\to O_C$ must be non-zero and thus an isomorphism, showing (A).
Finally, $p^*L$ is a degree zero line bundle and to show it is trivial, one only needs to show that it has a non-zero section. But,
$$H^0(p^*L)=H^0(p_*p^*L)=H^0(L\otimes(O_C\oplus L))=H^0(L\oplus O_C)\neq 0,$$
showing (B).

Just to clarify, this natural multiplication map $L^2\to O_C\oplus L$ is just induced canonically from restriction of multiplication inside algebra structure of $p_*O_D =O_C \oplus L$ to $L$, right?

Furthermore, when you write that if this map $L^2\to O_C\oplus L$ would have been zero, then by the existing nilpotents of $O_D$ you are refering to above are more precisely the local sections (...for $U \subset C$)$s_U \in L(U) \subset O_D(p^{-1}(U)$ with $s^2=0$, so more precisely you refering there the square zero elements, right? Are these the "nilpotent elements" you refered to in the answer?
